# How to connect to Postgres using Kerberos

Tags: postgresql, authentication, kerberos, datagrip

I have Postgres DB that uses kerberos authentication. So I configured my `/etc/krb5.conf` file, run `kinit` and now can use it, for example in python code:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="database.address.com",
    database="tested",
    user="username",
    port=5472
)

# Get version
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT VERSION()')
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)
```

It works perfectly, but sometime it is very useful to have ability to watch data in tables. I want to use DataGrip, but I can't figured out how to connect it to DB.

I found some old question about it: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000757404-DataGrip-Mac-Kerberos-Authentication-with-PostgreSQL

```
-Djava.security.krb5.realm=realm -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=kdc
```

but can't understand how to get correct values for `realm` and `kdc`

Answer (score 1):

1. Create file jaas.conf with following content:

> ```
> pgjdbc {
> com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
> useTicketCache=true
> debug=true
> renewTGT=true
> doNotPrompt=true;
> };
> ```

2. Open up data source properties, go to Advanced tab and add this to VM options field: `-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<path_to>/jaas.conf`
3. If it does not help and you have working krb5.conf also add this `-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf` to the VM options
4. If it still does not work, please ask your DBA for `kdc` and `realm` names.